# Obtener el valor más alto de 2 campos en el mismo registro

Tags: sql

Imaginar una tabla con los siguientes datos:

**ID** **valor1** **valor2**

**valor1** y **valor2** son numéricos.

Quiero saber de cada registro que valor es más alto

Comment: _No quiero imaginar:_ ¿Cómo se llama tu tabla? ¿`ID`, `valor1` y `valor2` son columnas de tu tabla?

Comment: Si y dentro de la misma fila cual es más alto valor1 o valor2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la instrucción CASE para comparar ambos valores, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Valor1 int = 10;
DECLARE @Valor2 int = 12;
SELECT CASE WHEN @Valor1 > @Valor2 THEN @Valor1 ELSE @Valor2 END
```

Comment: Esta opción es la que mejor se ajusta a lo que busco, también me sirve para saber si los valores son iguales. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Con un if se puede

```
SELECT id, if(valor1 > valor2, valor1, valor2) AS valor_maximo FROM tutabla
```

Básicamente la lógica de un if es `if(condición, valor_si_condición_se_cumple, valor_si_no_se_cumple)`